# How to select textarea and check if it is readonly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling with jQuery. I want to write a script which checks if the text area sharing the same parent (list item) with the button is read-only when that button is clicked. Here is the HTML:

```
...
<li>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:confirmDelete();">Delete</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:toggle();">Toggle</button>
  <textarea class="readOnly" readonly="true">Some text</textarea>
</li>
...
```

And the script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  ...    
  function toggle()
  {
    var textArea = $(this).parent("li").children("textarea");
    var isReadOnly = textArea.attr("readonly");
    if (isReadOnly == "true") {
      alert('It\'s read-only.');
    } else {
      alert('It\'s not read-only.');
    }
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

It appears that I cannot get passed the `var textArea = ...`

#### Update 1:

OK, I broke apart the selection in order to help myself analyze the problem:

```
...
var btn = $(this);
console.log(btn); //returns value, but not sure what exactly
var li = btn.parent();
console.log(li); //returns value, but not sure what exactly
var textArea = li.children('textarea');
console.log(textArea.prop('tagName')); //returns unidentified
```

So, there's the error. I can't seem to understand what is actually wrong, as I cannot really learn much if all the output I get from the debug is an object (and I don't even know what it represents; is it an element, or array ...) or `unidentified`. jQuery is not exactly intuitive.

Comment: When you say "can't get past ..." you should say specifically what is happening.

Break down the statement until you figure out where it fails:

    var ta= $(this);
    ta= ta.parent('li');
    ta= ta.children('textarea');

This will help you debug it...

I would use textArea.getAttribute('readonly');  It may not return true or false- inspect it in the console to see.

Comment: How do I utilize the console? I know almost nothing about jQuery ... Thanks!

Comment: Google for "Firebug" or Chrome Developer Tools.  You need to learn about how to debug JS before you learn jQuery.

Comment: I realized that I have a problem selecting tags. How do I select a textarea starting from the clicked button?

Comment: You've got a pretty bad syntax error in your code with the string `'It's read-only'`.

Comment: Agreed, I modified the question. However, the issue with not being able to select the textarea is happening even before the code execution reaches the badly written alert strings. Could you tell me why am I not able to select elements?

Answer (score 0):

The property is case sensitive. Try instead

```
var isReadOnly = textArea.attr("readOnly");
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is the only you likely need:

```
...find("textarea")[0];
```

not

```
...children("textarea");
```

or simply `$(this).siblings("textarea")[0];`

OR select directly

```
var mylist = $(this).siblings("textarea.readOnly");

if (mylist.length > 0)//true if it is
```

Comment: `$(this).siblings('textarea')[0];` is returning `unidentified`. It appears that the root of my problem is that I cannot select the textarea.

Comment: If you change your `var textArea` to `var mytextArea` do your results differ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in here.

Firs of all, turns out that when the attribute "readonly" is active, it doesn't have a "true" value, but a "readonly" value.

On the other hand, if you invoque a function by onclick (and I'm not 100% sure), you cannot use $(this). I'd recommend you to do (after giving some ID to the trigger button, or anything to identify it):

```
$(function() {

  $("button#my-button").bind("click", function() {
    if ($(this).siblings("textarea").attr("readonly") == "readonly") {
      alert("It's readonly");
    } else {
      alert ("It's not");
    }
  });

});
```